# How to reset FrameLayout or delete layout cache

Tags: android, android-layout, canvas, kotlin

In one of my canvas signature application, I am adding canvas view inside FrameLayout. It is working fine for me. Whenever I try to reset it the rendered content on view is removed but the cache is not cleared.

Please suggest me if anyone already did that...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried `View#invalidate`?

Comment: View#invalidate is not working for me. Thanks for your comment. Anyway, I have fixed this issue with a little change. if (myView.mBitmap != null) {
                        myView.mBitmap.eraseColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                        myView.mPath.reset();
                        //myView.invalidate();
                    }